# getSymbols.yahoo "method" in a loop with several symbols and corresponding dates in R

Tags: r, loops, download, symbols

"Method" `getSymbols.yahoo` allows putting a vector in lieu of the `Symbols` argument allowing the download of several tickers without using a loop:

```
library(quantmod)

someSymbols <- c("RMO", "NKLA", "JD", "AAPL", "IBM", "SPCE", "MRNA", "MPNGF")

getSymbols.yahoo(someSymbols, auto.assign = TRUE, env = globalenv())
```

However, this does not seem to work whe one adds a `date` vector of equal length in the `from =` argument, such as:

```
library(quantmod)

someSymbols <- c("RMO", "NKLA", "JD", "AAPL", "IBM", "SPCE", "MRNA", "MPNGF")
someDates <- as.Date(c(18659, 18659, 18659, 18901, 18901, 18659, 18901, 
                       18659), origin = "1970-01-01")

getSymbols.yahoo(someSymbols, auto.assign = TRUE, env = globalenv(), from = someDates)
```

My question:

- Whilst respective orders of `someSymbols` and `someDates` must be kept and with (preferably) only the `System Libraries` and `library(quantmod)` (without which `getSymbols.yahoo` does not work), what piece of code could download each symbol with its corresponding date?

Thanks in advance.

---

Systems used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 and macOS Big Sur version 11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Map` to pass one element at a time from each vector to the function.

```
library(quantmod)

someSymbols <- c("RMO", "NKLA", "JD", "AAPL", "IBM", "SPCE", "MRNA", "MPNGF")
someDates <- as.Date(c(18659, 18659, 18659, 18901, 18901, 18659, 18901, 
                       18659), origin = "1970-01-01")

Map(\(x, y) getSymbols(
  Symbols = x, 
  env = globalenv(), 
  auto.assign = TRUE, 
  from = y,
  src = "yahoo"), someSymbols, someDates)
```

Comment: Thank you Rui Barradas. Works exactly like I wanted: without any additional libraries.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `map2`

```
library(quantmod)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(someSymbols, someDates, ~ getSymbols(.x, 
                 env = globalenv(), 
                 auto.assign = TRUE,
                 from = .y, 
                 src = "yahoo"))
```

-checking

```
> head(RMO)
           RMO.Open RMO.High RMO.Low RMO.Close RMO.Volume RMO.Adjusted
2021-02-01    18.10    19.25   17.17     18.54    9507500        18.54
2021-02-02    19.01    19.42   18.01     18.64    5996100        18.64
2021-02-03    19.04    19.52   18.35     18.47    5531300        18.47
2021-02-04    18.98    19.16   17.93     18.44    5004800        18.44
2021-02-05    18.77    19.25   18.38     18.44    4862800        18.44
2021-02-08    18.73    20.00   18.52     19.36    5616900        19.36
> head(NKLA)
           NKLA.Open NKLA.High NKLA.Low NKLA.Close NKLA.Volume NKLA.Adjusted
2021-02-01     24.05    24.400    22.12      23.51    13861900         23.51
2021-02-02     23.74    23.970    22.56      23.00     8487200         23.00
2021-02-03     23.09    24.980    23.01      24.43    12034600         24.43
2021-02-04     24.46    25.225    23.82      24.42     8250700         24.42
2021-02-05     24.75    24.920    23.00      23.60     8481300         23.60
2021-02-08     23.51    23.980    23.17      23.50     7934000         23.50
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. Works perfectly, as always :)